# Выборка всех записей начиная с определенной

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, codeigniter

Привет, подскажите как сделать выборку всех записей из бд начиная с 6-й. Так же присутствует условие что значение одного поля должно быть равно 2. 
$this->db->select('*')->where('column2', 2)->get('table')
Что небходимо добавить в запрос?

Answer (score 0):

В запрос нужно добавить `LIMIT` [подробнее](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

Запрос типа: `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 18446744073709551615;`
В запросе выбор с 6го элемента по максимально возможный. [А максимальный в MyISAM (1.844E+19) элементов.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Для CodeIgniter в [мануале](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) написан пример `LIMIT`

`$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);`
что означает 
`// Executes: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10`

Значит в Вашей ситуации 
`$this->db->select('*')->where('column2', 2)->get('table', 18446744073709551615, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не понял вопрос до конца, но можно выбрать напрямую

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = 2;
```

или из временной таблицы

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` = 2) `subtable`
WHERE <...>;
```

И просто при разборе результата выбросить первые 6 элементов, в самом разборе или перед ним вызовом [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-shift.php)

Возможно не самый изящный ответ, но вопросу не хватает описания, на мой взгляд ) Не ясно, зачем нужны такие сложности